# Assign two Column values into JCombobox

Tags: java, mysql, swing, combobox, jcombobox

Could someone tell me how can I assign 2 column values to the JComboBox from mysql database. I want to hide one of the column and show only the other one. however, when retrieving the selected value from the combobox, I want to get the hidden value associated with the selected item."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store objects in your combo box:

```
public class TwoColumns {
    private String hiddenValue;
    private String displayedValue;

    // constructors, getters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return displayedValue;
    }
}
```

This is just an example: you should choose more meaninful names for the class and the fields.